# AngularJS filter object array with search term in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I´m currentrly trying to filter an array of objects with an search term from an input field.
I know there is a way to apply a search term to an ng-repeat directive using this code `ng-repeat="item in list| filter:search_term`. But I need to process the filtered list in the JavaScript part of the application. Is there a way how to access the filtered list in the JS part of the application or do I have to choose another approach to filter my array by an search term?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ymcfugzp/1/) is my (currently not working) example code.

**EDIT:**
I´m searching for a way to do the task completely without using a filter on my `ng-repeat`! At the end it should be possible to display the filtered list by only using a simple `ng-repeat="item in filtered_list`

Comment: You can pass the object from AngularJS to Javascript by adding it to window. *Ex:* window.sorted = vm.sortedData;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use filter in your controller also. Here is your updated fiddle. I hope this can help.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/ymcfugzp/3/`
```

Comment: Thank you! I searched for this kind of solution dealing with the filter in the JS Part of the application!

Answer (score 0):

You should filter it inside the `Component` then.

You can have a function that filters and also does your other processing stuff , similar as the one that follows:

```
myFilter(term) {
  const filtered = list.filter(element => element.term === term);
  // Do other stuff in here.
  return filtered;
}
```

Then your template could be as simple as that:

```
ng-repeat="myFilter(term)"
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a little working code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: `ng-repeat="item in filteredList = (list| filter:search_term)`.
And then just get your `filteredList` via `$scope.filteredList`.

Or use controller alias like this:
`ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.filteredList = ($ctrl.list| filter:search_term)`
- in order to not keep data in `$scope`